# Actionscript: NetStream stutters after buffering

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, streaming

Using NetStream to stream content from http, I've noticed that esp with certain exported h264's, if the player encounters an empty buffer, it will stop and buffer to the requested length (as expected).

However once the buffer is full, the playback doesn't resume, but instead jumps ahead, as such- instantly playing the buffered duration in a brief moment, and thusly triggering an empty buffer again.. this will then continue over and over.

Presumably when the netstream pauses to buffer, the playhead position continues, and the player is attempting to snap to that position on resume- however given it could take 5 seconds to build a 2 second buffer- it ends up with a useless buffer again..

(this is an assumption)

I've attempted to work around this by listening for an empty buffer netstatus event, pausing the stream, and at the same time setting up a loop to check the current buffer length vs the requested buffer length.. and resuming once the buffer length is greater than or equal to the requested buffer.. however this causes problems when there isn't enough of the video remaining.. for example, a 10 second buffer with only 5 seconds remaining, the loop just sits there waiting for a buffer length of 10 seconds when theres only 5 left...

You would think that you could simply check which was smaller, the time left or the requested buffer length.. however the times flash gives are not accurate..

If you add the net streams current time index, plus the buffered time, the total is not the entire duration of the movie (when at the end).. it is close but not the same.

This brings me back to the original problem, and if there is another way to fix this, clearly flash knows when the buffer is ready, so how can i get flash pause when it buffers, and resume once the buffer is ready? currently it doesn't.. it pauses and then once the buffer is full- it plays the entire buffered content in about .1 of a second.

Thanks in advance,
Stephen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright well, plenty of searching around (wow, how hard is it to describe this problem).. I guess additionally the problem is related to lower bandwidth and a lot of people may not test this scenario..

So anyway, plenty of people experiencing this issue- seems dependant on the codec settings- perhaps keyframing or how the streaming hints work.. I've no idea.

What I do know is this shouldn't be a concern to the player, flash yet again becomes a huge let down..

BUT, I did manage to make a hack to resolve this issue, if you listen to the netstatus event, and wait for an empty buffer event, you pause the stream.. ideally now you listen for a buffer full event, and resume it- but since the stream is paused- the buffer doesn't build (but of course, the video is still being loaded in).

If you now set a timer (I set an event on enter frame), and listen for one of two conditions to become true:

- a) the bufferLength is greater than
  or equal to the bufferTime (actual
  buffer is at least requested buffer
  size)
- b) the loaded bytes count
  equals the total bytes count

Condition A isn't enough because at the end of the video, the bufferLength may not be able to fit the requested buffer size because the time remaining is less, and checking the current playhead location + actual buffer length at this time does not equal the duration of the movie, so this is why condition B is needed, you check that the actual movie is completely loaded, and as such playable.

Here's my code if at all useful to anyone:

```
function onNetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void

    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") {

        ns.pause();

        playerRoot.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function() { 
            if (ns.bufferLength >= ns.bufferTime || ns.bytesLoaded == ns.bytesTotal) {
                playerRoot.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
                ns.resume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I never encountered the problem you described. Does it happen on every video?

One thing you can try is streaming your video with JW Player to see if the same problem happens (http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/). This is an open source video player built in AS3.

Comment: Hi David, no it doesn't happen on every video- so presumably its an encoding problem.. which is a nightmare. It's encoded as h264 from camtasia, keyframes every second.. I think I'll try a few different exports to try and nail the problem- if I find it I'll post back. Thanks